# Remove element by attribute name with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried it with jQuery and it was working fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[title='Book'],a[title='Movie'],a[title='Music']").remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Book">Book</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Movie">Movie</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Music">Music</a>
```

But I prefer to use plain Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an element by a CSS selector, you use:

- **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**

  This will find the first matching element and return a node reference or undefined (if no node was matched).
- **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

  This will return a node list (a.k.a HTML Element Collection) of all matching elements or an empty node list (if no elements were matched).

So, to find and gather up all your `<a>` elements that need to be removed:

```
var anchors =  document.querySelectorAll("a[title='Book'], 
                                          a[title='Movie'],
                                          a[title='Music']");
```

And, in the **[DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)** (the native API for DOM access), you need to use **[`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)**, which requires you to get a reference to the parent element of the element you wish to remove.

> **NOTE**: Newer browsers may support the **[`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)** method,
>   which doesn't require access to the parent and removes the specified
>   element directly. But, currently, for best compatibility, use `.removeChild()`.

So, all together (this code could be combined to reduce it, but is shown in each part for clarity):

```js
// Get reference to nodes to be removed
var children = document.querySelectorAll("a[title='Book'], a[title='Movie'], a[title='Music']");

// Turn children node list into actual JavaScript Array
// (so that .forEach() can be used successfully in all modern browsers).
var childArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(children);

// Loop through the child array and get the parent node for
// each child, then remove each child
childArray.forEach(function(child){
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Book">Book</a>
  <a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Movie">Movie</a>
  <a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Music">Music</a>

  <!-- This anchor will not be removed because it is not matched
       by the selector passed to .querySelectorAll() -->
  <a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Other">Other</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [ibrahim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46257049/8559830) answer works well too, but this is what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`document.querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [**`parentElement.removeChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[title='Book'],a[title='Movie'],a[title='Music']").forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
});
```

**Note 1:** You can use [**`childNode.remove`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) instead of `parentElement.removeChild`, but bear in mind that it is not supported by all browser (IE for example is not supporting it at all):

```
e.remove();   // instead of e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
```

**Note 2:** `NodeList.forEach` is also not supported by some older browser, if it causes some problem, you could always use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements.

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a[title='Book'],a[title='Movie'],a[title='Music']").forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
});
```

```html
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Book">Book</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Movie">Movie</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Other">Other</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Music">Music</a>
```

Comment: You don't need parentElement, its enough to call remove() on a node. More here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove`

Comment: @Goran.it `.remove` is surely shorter, but it is not supported by all browser. `parentElement.removeChild` is safer (for now).

Comment: @Goran.it but I'll add as a note.

Comment: Not all browsers support `.forEach` on the node list returned from `.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You got me. Same applies for `Array.from`, ehem ehem.

Comment: I've written it that way for readability by newbies. In practice `[].slice.call()`.

Answer (score 0):

For older browsers, using `getElementsByTagName` and filtering, just for completeness

```js
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).filter(function(el) {
  return ['Book','Movie','Music'].indexOf(el.title) !== -1;
}).forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

```html
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Book">Book</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Movie">Movie</a>
<a class="label-block" href="#" rel="tag" title="Music">Music</a>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live node list, which isn't right (performance wise) for most use cases.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - you do know that live nodelists are faster and more performant than static nodelists, simply because they fetch the data as needed, and not all at once when created, like static nodelists? Not that anyone will ever notice the difference.

Comment: I do know how they work, but would not agree that they are faster and more performant. They defer the actual DOM search until accessed and therein lies the problem. If the reference is accessed multiple times, but the DOM structure hasn't changed, they are doing those extra searches for nothing. That's why I say that they should be reserved for certain use cases, namely when the DOM will undergo dynamic modifications.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - that's micro-micro-micro optimization, in most cases `getElementsBy..` will be faster because it doesn't have to create an entire map of the collection, it's live and gotten from the DOM on access. In some cases, as you say, a static nodelist will be more performant, but you'll never notice the difference. In this case, it doesn't really matter anyway, when the HTMLCollection is sliced, it's a regular array containing DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Do as:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("a[title='Book'],a[title='Movie'],a[title='Music']");

[].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
    item.remove();
});
```

as in https://jsfiddle.net/yr8787dy/.
There is no need to access the parent node.

Comment: As has been pointed out in other answers, `.remove()` is not supported in all browsers yet.