# Removing and Adding CSS-Class to DIV-Container based on the Title-Attribute of HTML-Element

Tags: javascript, shopware6

I want to append a CSS-Class if a link is clicked on my website based on the "title-attribute" in the link-element.

For example: If I click on the link with the title "Brand" it should append a CSS-Class called "active" on my link-class. (nav-link main-navigation-link)

The CSS-Class "active" should also be removed if I click on another link the website and navigate to a another category.

This would be the final output:

```
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link active" href="#" itemprop="url" title="Brand">
```

this is my HTML-Code:

```
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link" href="#" itemprop="url" title="Brand">
   <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
      <span itemprop="name">Brand</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

How I can add a CSS-Class by JavaScript using only the "title-attribute"?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is a title-tag: `<title> ... </title>` This is an attribute called title: `<a title="...">` ... What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I´m sorry. I mean the attribute title: "title="Brand"

Comment: I would suggest you add a specific class in the `twig` template for these specific tags, so you do not need to change your Javascript when you add translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this.

HTML

```
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link" href="#" itemprop="url" title="Brand" onclick="handleOnClick(this)">
   <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
      <span itemprop="name">Brand</span>
   </div>
</a>
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link" href="#" itemprop="url" title="Product"  onclick="handleOnClick(this)">
   <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
      <span itemprop="name">Product</span>
   </div>
</a>
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link" href="#" itemprop="url"  onclick="handleOnClick(this)">
   <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
      <span itemprop="name">No Title</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

JS

```
function handleOnClick(_this){
document.querySelectorAll('.main-navigation-link').forEach(link => {
    link.classList.remove('active');
    });
    if(_this.getAttribute('title') == "Brand"){
            _this.classList.add('active')
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But it should only append the css-class "active" if the titel is "brand". If the title is not "brand" there is nothing which should appended.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46257053/9787555

You can use `.querySelector()` or `.querySelectorAll()` to find the nodes and delete them accordingly.